# Graphics output issue while installing Mac OS 9 on old Power Macintosh G3

Tags: classic-mac-os

I'm trying to resurrect an Apple Power Macintosh G3 300 (Blue & White).

I get the "question folder" icon when I turn it on normally.

I burned an iso of Mac OS 9.2.2 and popped it into the optical drive. Screens I see:

- "question folder"
- blank screen w/ mouse pointer
- happy mac icon
- "Mac OS 9.2 Welcome to Mac OS"
- "Mac OS 9.2 Starting up" + waiting mouse cursor + loading bar w/ puzzle-piece icons on the bottom
- screen goes dead, monitor reports "OUT OF RANGE"

I'm speculating that the mac is outputting an unusual resolution that my run-of-the-mill 1080 monitor can't make sense of over VGA.

**What should I do so I can finish installing w/out flying blind?** Options I'm considering:

- finding another VGA monitor
- googling video of classic mac os install and copying key sequence
- burning a different iso

Answer (score 1):

turns out the mac from '99 was outputting higher than 1080. Worked just fine when I connected it to a higher-rez monitor.